# how to take print out from a network attached printer

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printing, printer, network-printer

I have a printer cum photo state machine connected in my lan.
Each time I fire  a print I have to go to settings of printer on document
like in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdzRM.jpg) (low reputation so screenshot is attached as link)
and disable color print then enable color print.
Then I take print out.

How can I do setting so that I can directly take print out black and white.
It is PLC V6 driver for universal printing preference installed.
The printer I have to use is  a Ricoh MP C2003 photo state machine.
I do not know how to access it  for taking print outs easily.
I think some device driver  r91379L1a
http://support.ricoh.com/bb/html/dr_ut_e/re2/model/mpc2003/mpc2003.htm
is installed on my laptop. But each time I have to open printer
settings to take print out other wise it
wont print. Is there a better solution for this.
Is there a better solution for this. Meaning I don't
want to open printer settings again and again for
taking one or 2 page print out.
I use Windows 10.

Comment: Well you can create a virtual printer, set the default settings to print B&W and call it Printer - Black. When you want to print something just change the printer.

Comment: Try adjusting the settings in windows and not through the application.  Print drivers store their settings in two different places dependent on who is running them (system or app).  If it still doesn't work, you might need to remove the printer entirely (to clear the registry).. reinstall, then do the settings through "devices and printers".. and not through the app print dialog.  BTW, I wrote windows print drivers for over 8 years.  My guess might not fix you.. but I know what I am talking about.

Comment: Also.. @User552853 has a good suggestion.   I wouldn't call it a "virtual printer".. it's just another instance of the driver.. but I have used this method for years.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas actually I could not understand any of the suggestions you all gave. I need step by step instructions of using virtual printer or even if you said like changing settings in windows.

Comment: Uninstall printer from "devices and printers".  Re-add printer.  Go to settings right there in "devices and printers" control panel.  Change to black and white.. (or whatever you like).  The setting should be there for any program you open.